# need help in Java passing objects

Tags: java

UPDATE:
i modified the hashCode, now is a little better. :) but the problem is still there... :(

so, and modified my method too:

```
private Node getMinNode()
{

    int min = 9999999;   //value
    Node minNode = new Node(); //key,index

    for (Node key : this.distances.keySet()) {

        int minOfNode= this.distances.get(key);

        System.out.println("Key "+ key +", Value = " + minOfNode);

        if(minOfNode<min)
        {
           min= minOfNode;
           minNode= key;
           System.out.println("Key minNode = " + minNode + ", Value minNode = " + minOfNode);

        }
    }

    return minNode;

}
```

and there is the output: (the whitespace(, ,) in the lines would be an empty char) and this is not the end... this is only the first few row...

```
   Key 66601, 3546492, 3546493, 228, f, Value = 9999999
   Key 77393, 3628185, 3628186, 64, t, Value = 9999999
   Key 0, 0, 0, 0, , Value = 0 
   Key minNode = 0, 0, 0, 0, , Value minNode = 0
   Key 66601, 3546492, 3546493, 228, f, Value = 9999999 
   Key 77393, 3628185, 3628186, 64, t, Value = 9999999
```

(note: the element with 'Key 0, 0, 0, 0, , Value = 0' does exists, this is the startNode)
in that constructor the attribs are initialized with the zeros, i know,
so my main problem is, why is that happening? they are passed rigth out of the if(), but in the if() they arent
i hope it's clearer what is my problem. :)

Comment: `key` and `minOfNode` are not changed in the loop, are you sure the two `println`s don't print the same message? Can you show us the output? Also, you might want to slightly modify the second `println`, so that they are better distinguishable.

Comment: i was wrong, it prints in the first println this too: Key = 0, 0, 0, 0, , Value = 9999999 , hundreds of rows long..., and it doesnt enter in the if() too

Comment: Update your question. You have to give us more information if you want help.

Comment: note: the element with 'Key 0, 0, 0, 0, , Value = 0' does exists, this is the startNode

Comment: The output looks reasonable (maybe except that the value is always 99999, check that your map is correctly filled here). You are looking for the closest node, which is `0,0,0,0` at distance `0`, so the algorithm works as designed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all storing min and minNode - isn't quite good practice, they aren't necessary.

Next, passing an entire Map to method is better than using global variables (of cource if u trully don't neet it)

Map.keySet() - returns a list of keys, seems like u need Map.getEntrySet() method, to retrieve all 'nodes' (in usual Map they are called Entry)

your code should be like this:

```
    private Map.Entry getMinNode(Map<String, Integer> distances) {
    Map.Entry minNode = null;

    for (Map.Entry node : distances.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key = " + node.getKey()+ ", Value = " + node.getValue());

        if (minNode == null || node.getValue() < minNode.getValue()) {
           minNode = node;
        }
    }
    return minNode;
}
```

You should look at JavaDoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: thanks for your reply! it would be a simple MinSearch, but i need to get that Node (only Node) which belongs to the lowest int value. but i dont understand when i make a another instance of the 'Node key' like  Node index = key; it's good, but when i passed it through the 'Node key' in the if(), like  minNode= key; it doesnt work, and prints out stupids. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1):

First, @StrekoZ is partly right.  If you iterated over the entrySet, there would be no need to call `get(key)`.

But I'm not sure what is causing your problem.  A couple of theories:

- The distance values stored in the map really are zero; i.e. the problem is in whatever is creating the entries.
- Your `Key` class does not implement `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` correctly.
- Your `Key` objects are mutable, and something is mutating them in a way that is changing their hashcode values *while they are in the map*.

The last two could both cause keys to show up in the keySet, but to be missing when you do a `get` using them.

**UPDATE** - the output in your updated question is most consistent with my first theory; i.e. the distance values in the map are incorrect.